# How to write a lambda function which gets executed after TEdgeBrowser ExecuteScript?

Tags: c++builder, tedgebrowser

I have `TEdgeBrowser` and I am using `ExecuteScript` method from the `DefaultInterface` like this:

`EdgeBrowser1->DefaultInterface->ExecuteScript()`

`ExecuteScript`, when called this way takes 2 parameters:

`System::WideChar * javaScript` and `const _di_ICoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler handler`

What I want to write is a lambda function (using **clang** compiler) which gets executed (and destroyed) after a script is executed...

Something like:

```cpp
    EdgeBrowser1->DefaultInterface->(L"alert('Hello World!')",
        _di_ICoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler(
            new TCppInterfacedObject<TCoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler>(
                [](HRESULT errorCode, PCWSTR resultObjectAsJson) -> HRESULT {
                    if (FAILED(errorCode))
                    {
                        ShowMessage("Failed to execute script");
                        return errorCode;
                    }
                    ShowMessage("Script executed successfully");
                    return S_OK;
                })));
```

However, `TCoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler` doesn't seem to be defined? What do I need to insert there to make it work?

**EDIT**:

A few issues I encountered with otherwise excellent reply by @RemyLebeau

1. in `WebView2.hpp` the second parameter of `Invoke` is defined as `System::WideChar *` so I couldn't use `LPCWSTR` as it reported that the virtual method `Invoke` is unimplemented. Also there wasn't a `__stdcall`. Corrected by using instead:

```cpp
HRESULT __stdcall Invoke(HRESULT errorCode, System::WideChar* resultObjectAsJson)
```

2. is the use of `INTFOBJECT_IMPL_IUNKNOWN` really necessary since the [TCppInterfacedObject](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TCppInterfacedObject) documentation describes that it already implements `IUnknown` methods like `QueryInterface`, `AddRef`, and `Release`? When commented out, there is no warning that those methods are unimplemented, like when it is when I "manually" implement the `ICoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler`
3. Is it necessary to `Release()` the object before it returns S_OK? I know that there is reference counting involved but does the `ExecuteScript` call then does that? Basically, after executing the lambda or instance of `ICoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler`, it is no longer needed to be in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`TEdgeBrowser::DefaultInterface`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Edge.TCustomEdgeBrowser.DefaultInterface) property is the raw [`ICoreWebView2*`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2?view=webview2-1.0.1901.177) interface pointer provided by Microsoft, just wrapped in the [`DelphiInterface`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DelphiInterface) class (that is what the `_di_` prefix refers to).  Microsoft has no concept of `_di_` wrapper types.

The 2nd parameter of `ICoreWebView2::ExecuteScript()` expects a pointer to an object that implements the [`ICoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2executescriptcompletedhandler?view=webview2-1.0.1938.49) interface. You can't pass in a lambda where an interface is expected.  So, you need to write a class that implements `ICoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler`, and then pass an object instance of that class to `ExecuteScript()`.

The way you are trying to use [`TCppInterfacedObject`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TCppInterfacedObject) for that purpose is not correct. Try this instead:

```
class TCoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler : public TCppInterfacedObject<ICoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler>
{
public:
    HRESULT __stdcall Invoke(HRESULT errorCode, WideChar* resultObjectAsJson)
    {
        if (FAILED(errorCode))
        {
            ShowMessage("Failed to execute script");
            return errorCode;
        }
        ShowMessage("Script executed successfully");
        return S_OK;
    }
};

EdgeBrowser1->DefaultInterface->ExecuteScript(
    L"alert('Hello World!')",
    _di_ICoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler(
        new TCoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler()
    )
);
```

If you really want to use a lambda, then you would need something more like this instead:

```
#include <functional>

class TCoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler : public TCppInterfacedObject<ICoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler>
{
public:
    using funcType = std::function<HRESULT(HRESULT, LPCWSTR)>;

    TCoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler(funcType func) : m_func(func) {}

    HRESULT __stdcall Invoke(HRESULT errorCode, WideChar* resultObjectAsJson)
    {
        return m_func(errorCode, resultObjectAsJson);
    }

private:
    funcType m_func;
};

EdgeBrowser1->DefaultInterface->ExecuteScript(
    L"alert('Hello World!')",
    _di_ICoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler(
        new TCoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler(
            [](HRESULT errorCode, LPCWSTR resultObjectAsJson) -> HRESULT
            {
                if (FAILED(errorCode))
                {
                    ShowMessage("Failed to execute script");
                    return errorCode;
                }
                ShowMessage("Script executed successfully");
                return S_OK;
            }
        }
    )
);
```

Alternatively:

```
template<typename FuncType>
class TCoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler : public TCppInterfacedObject<ICoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler>
{
public:
    TCoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler(FuncType func) : m_func(func) {}

    HRESULT __stdcall Invoke(HRESULT errorCode, WideChar* resultObjectAsJson)
    {
        return m_func(errorCode, resultObjectAsJson);
    }

private:
    FuncType m_func;
};

auto func = [](HRESULT errorCode, LPCWSTR resultObjectAsJson) -> HRESULT
{
    if (FAILED(errorCode))
    {
        ShowMessage("Failed to execute script");
        return errorCode;
    }
    ShowMessage("Script executed successfully");
    return S_OK;
};

EdgeBrowser1->DefaultInterface->ExecuteScript(
    L"alert('Hello World!')",
    _di_ICoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler(
        new TCoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler<decltype(func)>(func)
    )
);
```

And no, you should not call `Release()` from inside the handler itself.  `ExecuteScript()` will `AddRef()` the handler that you pass in if needed, and then `Release()` it when done using it.  You should only `AddRef()`/`Release()` your own references to the handler.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to make it work, but I added 2 notes in my question (which are too long for the comment) as the code as it is above doesn't work without a few modifications.

Comment: @Coder12345 I updated my answer to address your concerns.